# rails.js's purpose

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ujs

I am getting acquainted with Rails 3, UJS and JQuery. I understand why jquery.js and application.js are needed but why is rails.js needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it as the missing link between jQuery and Rails. Suppose you have a form tag,

```
<form method="POST" action="/some/path" data-remote="true">
  ..
</form>
```

The code that will look at the `data-remote` on this form tag and other such attributes used that Rails looks at, and submit this form through AJAX is handled by rails.js. It is like a connector between Rails and jQuery. The source is rather simple which you can read at https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js

Comment: So I just copy the contents from https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js to my rails.js?

Comment: I also found another source for rails.js at https://github.com/overture8/jquery-rails3-uj/blob/master/public/javascripts/rails.js. Which one is definitive source?

Comment: Never mind, I think I get it. Your link is the official source, my link is an outdated version that was included in a demo app. In case anyone else is wondering, the answer is yes, I just copy the contents from the official source to my rails.js.

Comment: Quick question: is there a cloud-hosted version of the rails kind of like with jquery? All I need to do is link to google's jquery URL and I'll have the latest jQuery, is there such a thing for rails.js?

Comment: Rails 3.1 comes officially bundles with this now.

Comment: That's what I heard about Rails 3.1 but I expect it to be a copy and not a live link to a cloud version. Can someone confirm?