# Why is my link still submitting with Post when I've changed data-bind="delete" Rails

Tags: jquery, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following link:

`<a href="/kits?resource_id=536" class="authorize spin" data-method="post" data-remote="true" id="use_it_link_171" rel="nofollow">`

After I create the kit I change the link as follows:

`<a href="/kits/536" class="authorize spin" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" id="use_it_link_171" rel="nofollow">`

I changed the href and the data-method so that it should submit to the destroy action. However its still being submitted as POST

Why is that and how can I fix this so its submits as a 'delete'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because Rails uses unobstrusive javascript to set the behavior of tags like `<a data-remote="xxx">` or `<a data-method="xxx">` (in fact Rails creates an hidden form in your page that is submited when the link is clicked). It's done at page loading by [rails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645583/rails-jss-purpose).

So when you change the `data-method` attribute of the link, it's "too late", it does not changes the behavior of the link (you should update the hidden form for this). You could dig into `rails.js` code to find how to do it, but I suggest that you create 2 links in your page (one with `data-method="post"` and one with `data-method="delete"`), and use CSS to hide/display only the useful link.