# jquery and data-method in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have two simple links:

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-remote="true" data-method="post" href="/entry_votes?id=129">LINK+</a> 
<a rel="nofollow" data-remote="true" data-method="delete" href="/entry_votes/129">LINK-</a>
```

First one starts #create action, second one #destroy.

Using jquery I change first link, so `data-method = "delete"`, `href="/entry_votes/129"`, I click on this new link and still get `"Started POST /entry_votes/129"` in server logs. Do you know why?

Comment: Please post the jQuery code you are using?

Comment: Can you please post your jQuery code where you change the `data-method` and also the `click()` handler.

Comment: I think I found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352592/why-is-my-link-still-submitting-with-post-when-ive-changed-data-bind-delete-r

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my link still submitting with Post when I've changed data-bind="delete" Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352592/why-is-my-link-still-submitting-with-post-when-ive-changed-data-bind-delete-r)

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought this was a duplicate of the question in the comments, but turns out that `rails.js` only sends `GET` and `POST` requests.

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/Unobtrusive-scripting-support-for-jQuery#data-method-links-that-result-in-post-put-or-delete-requests

> Note for non-Rails backends: because submitting forms with HTTP
>   methods other than GET and POST isn't widely supported across
>   browsers, all other HTTP methods are actually sent over POST with the
>   intended method indicated in the "_method" parameter. Rails framework
>   automatically detects and compensates for this.